# How do I replace Warsaw black to someting else, like color theme beaver does?

Tags: beamer, color, themes

The Warsaw theme uses black for the left half of top and bottom bars, and blue for the right half. Theme color beaver replaces these two colors with two shades of gray. How can I do the same within my .tex file?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina That's great thank you! But where can I find this kind of information? Is there any documentation on colors? On my MikTek distribution I don't even have the sources of those color styles aparently. How can I know which colors I have to change to obtain the desired effect? For instance what is the name of the color of the bar just below the top bar, the one in which frame title appears?

Comment: You're welcome. The main source of information is the [beamer manual](http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). You can find information about colors in Sections 17.2, 17.3, 17.4, and 17.5, and under the little paragraphs (scattered throughout the manual) that begin with *Beamer-Template/-Color/-Font* or *Beamer-Color/-Font*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those colors are controlled by `palette primary` and `palette quaternary`, so you can redefine them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=gray!60}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=gray!30!black}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Four}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Five}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the palettes will also affect some other elements of the theme; if you just want to change the colors for the headline and footline, you can simply change the `section in head/foot`, and `subsection in head/foot colors`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=gray!20!black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Four}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Five}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you just want to use the `beaver` color theme with `Warsaw`, then simply say

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Two}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Three}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Four}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}
\section{Five}
\begin{frame}test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```